# C# DataGridView bound to SortedBindingList not showing sort

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindinglist

I have implemented the SortedBindingList class shown at http://www.martinwilley.com/net/code/forms/sortablebindinglist.html

I have then successfully added objects of the same type to it.

I have a DataGridView on a form with a BindingSource that is set to the list. When I click a column header, the list sorts in the SortedBindingList object, however that change is not reflected in the DataGridView. Is there a property on the DataGridView I need to set or an event I need to subscribe to?

```
SortedBindingList<CustomObject> list = new SortedBindingList<CustomObject>();
//Add Objects to list
CustomObjectBindingSource.DataSource = list; 
dataGridViewSource1.DataSource = CustomObjectBindingSource;
```

If I put a breakpoint in the SortedBindingList code in the Compare method where it returns the result, I can see that the list is sorted appropriately, just the DataGridview does not show the list as being sorted. What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Sorry! for some reason I thought it was asp.net

In your case,  you need

```
   BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
   bs.DataSource = bs;
   dataGridView.DataSource = bs;
```

EDIT 2:

I just tried this using the SortableBindingList class like this

```
    SortableBindingList<Person> list = new SortableBindingList<Person>();
    list.Add(new Person{Name = "abc",Email = "def"});
    list.Add(new Person { Name = "bcd", Email = "aqz" });
    dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
```

for

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

and it works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I am a bit confused by it. I don't see a DataBind() method available on the DataGridView or the BindingSource I am setting it to. Can you be more specific about which object has that DataBind() method?

Comment: Thanks again StackOverflowException. Isn't that the same thing I am already doing? The only difference is the variable names from what I can tell. I am assuming, perhaps wrongly, that bs.DataSource should be set to the list and not back to the DataSource itself.

Comment: Solved it... had one stupid coding error. List<T> list = Items as List<T> is important. I had declared that differently and didn't even realize it.